# What are the black spots on my paw paws and how do I treat them?

Tags: fruit-trees, plant-health, diseases

I have six paw paw trees, all of which were going fine, then almost all together started to develop these black spots on the leaves and fruit.

It has progressively gotten worse, and caused most of the leaves to fall off, the fruit seems to suffers severely from it, and either falls of or rots on the tree.

Is this common, what can I do to remedy the situation?

I've tried a copper based anti fungus spray, as well as white oil, and also just generally improving the soil with fertiliser, and manure.

The affected leaves fall off, new leaves shoot, and soon they suffer the same fate.

[image]

Comment: This doesn't look like the Paw Paw that we have in the eastern U.S. It looks more like a Papaya. Could you give information about your location, weather, soil type, etc. or the scientific name of the tree in question if possible?

Comment: Australia, in the Sydney region. I'm not sure what type they are. I've grown them from seed from bought fruit sold as paw paw and red paw paw.

Comment: From a quick bit of research, it seems that in Australia, among other places, papaya is often called paw paw. This is definitely *Carica papaya*, not *Asimina triloba* which is native to the eastern US and also called a pawpaw.

Comment: Any fuzz visible around those necrotic leaf or fruit lesions? You could easily have two different problems. Doesn't look like papaya ringspot virus: https://www.google.com/search?q=papaya+virus+spot&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0CAcQ_AUoAWoVChMIjYqk6uW3xwIVg1CSCh0iKgc_&biw=703&bih=422#tbm=isch&q=papaya+ringspot+virus Might be fungusy: https://www.google.com/search?q=papaya+virus+spot&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0CAcQ_AUoAWoVChMIjYqk6uW3xwIVg1CSCh0iKgc_&biw=703&bih=422#tbm=isch&q=papaya+fungus

Comment: No, the edges are clean and smooth. On the fruit they dip in a little which led me think they might be some sort of a sting, but I can't find any critters  on the trees or fruit to back up the ideal.

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like its infected with a fungus - Asperisporium caricae is a candidate, but this infection and others are just called black spot infections. If you've had damp weather, that makes it worse. Consistent application of fungicides seems to be the only way to keep it in check. Link below might be of some use, scroll down to Black Spot

https://www.plantvillage.com/en/topics/papaya-pawpaw/infos/diseases_and_pests_description_uses_propagation